# How can I disable mouseWheelZoom in OpenLayers 7?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-7

I have just updated from OpenLayers 6 to version 7. I now get an error regarding the interactions. I want to disable the zoom so the page can be scrolled. Only when using "platformModifierKeyOnly" zooming via scroll should be possible. This is the code that used to work:

```
const map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [clusterHulls, clusters, clusterCircles],
    target: 'map',
    view: view,
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults({
        dragPan: false,
        mouseWheelZoom: false
    }).extend([
        new ol.interaction.DragPan({
            condition: function (event) {
                return this.getPointerCount() === 2 || ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly(event);
            },
        }),
        new ol.interaction.MouseWheelZoom({
            condition: ol.events.condition.platformModifierKeyOnly,
        }),
    ]),
});
```

But now I get the following error in the console: `ol.interaction.defaults is not a function`.

Unfortunately the OpenLayers documentation doesn't help much to find out what needs to be changed to get this working again.

Comment: Have you [imported `defaults`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_defaults)?

Comment: In OL7 you need `ol.interaction.defaults.defaults`

Comment: Thanks @Mike! Is there a chance I could have found out about this in the docs? It's kind of hard for me to understand it. If you write this as an answer, I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OpenLayers 7 the syntax is is `ol.interaction.defaults.defaults`

See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/14020